# How to construct MySQL query to get Products with all selected Features?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN features_products fp ON p.id = fp.product_id 
WHERE fp.feature_id in (1,5,11)
```

This query returns all Products that have at least one of given Feature ids (1 or 5 or 11).

I need is a list of Products that have all 3 *(1 and 5 and 11)*

Help!

Comment: Are the feature ids aggregated (many to 1)?  Or are there potentially 3 different entries?  We need more info.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure and some sample data it is hard to know how feature_id is shown to be 1,5 and 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I think the best approach is aggregation, because it provides the most flexibility.  Here is how you would find the products with all three features:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     features_products fp
     ON p.id = fp.product_id
group by p.id
having sum(fp.feature_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(fp.feature_id = 5) > 0 and
       sum(fp.feature_id = 11) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is checking for the existence of one product.  What makes this flexible is if you wanted to have inclusion and exclusion lists.  For instance, always has 1 and 5, but never 11:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     features_products fp
     ON p.id = fp.product_id
group by p.id
having sum(fp.feature_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(fp.feature_id = 5) > 0 and
       sum(fp.feature_id = 11) = 0;
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to *first* present the more conventional approach and *then* state why you think your method is better.